# jni4net on Docker Ubuntu Host

Tags: java, spring, ubuntu, docker, jni4net

I have a application developed in Java 8 with SpringBoot, that use jni4net for consuming a dll library.

It's posibble make a docker container in Ubuntu to run this application ?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Spring Boot with Docker

This guide walks you through the process of building a Docker image for running a Spring Boot application.
What you’ll build

Docker is a Linux container management toolkit with a "social" aspect, allowing users to publish container images and consume those published by others. A Docker image is a recipe for running a containerized process, and in this guide we will build one for a simple Spring boot application.
What you’ll need

```
About 15 minutes

A favorite text editor or IDE

JDK 1.8 or later

Gradle 2.3+ or Maven 3.0+

You can also import the code straight into your IDE:

    Spring Tool Suite (STS)

    IntelliJ IDEA
```

If you are NOT using a Linux machine, you will need a virtualized server. By installing VirtualBox, other tools like the Mac’s boot2docker, can seamlessly manage it for you. Visit VirtualBox’s download site and pick the version for your machine. Download and install. Don’t worry about actually running it.

You will also need Docker, which only runs on 64-bit machines. See https://docs.docker.com/installation/#installation for details on setting Docker up for your machine. Before proceeding further, verify you can run docker commands from the shell. If you are using boot2docker you need to run that first.

Comment: Hello. I use Docker, I Know Docker. The problem is run jni4net on Linux container. Because jni4net need .net framework, and .net run on windows.